dbt_utils.union_relations, 'Test_concat__dbt_tmp_temp_view' is specified more than once
I am using dbt_utils.union_relations instead of union all since my tables have many columns.
However I get an error with the column [%Datekey] that exists in both tables (see the error below). %Datekey only exists once in each table, if I rename %Datekey in one of the tables the script works.
The error

14:57:53  ('42S21', "[42S21] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name '%DateKey' in view or function 'Test_concat__dbt_tmp_temp_view' is specified more than once. (4506) (SQLMoreResults)")

I have have checked the type and they are the same. The function works with other tables, that has %Datekey

Have you checked target/compiled/your_model.sql? Do you see there duplicates of %Datekey? If you can edit your answer and add the reduced (please add only essential part) version of compiled file to it, that would be helpful.
